# How is SimpleMembershipProvider wired in MVC4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, simplemembership

We created a CustomSimpleMembershipProvider in a asp.net mvc4 internet template like so

```
public class MySimpleMembershipProvider : SimpleMembershipProvider    {
    public override bool RequiresUniqueEmail        {
        get            {                return true;            }
    }
}
```

But using this seems to be a mystery as

- there's no web.config entry
- there are no references to SimpleMembershipProvider in 
    InitializeSimpleMembershipAttribute or
    SimpleMembershipInitializer
   so can't change it there

so the question is - where is the wiring for SimpleMembershipProvider in asp.net mvc4 and how to change it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wired up in the web.config. You should have an entry in the web.config as shown below if you created it using the Internet template.

```
    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SimpleRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleRoleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
  </providers>
</roleManager>
<membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

You need to change the entry for membership to something like this:

```
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="MyAssembly.MyNamespace.MySimpleMembershipProvider, MyAssembly" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

But creating your own provider that inherits from the SimpleMembershipProvider may not be the best way to achieve your goals. SimpleMembership is easy to customize without modifying the provider as [demonstrated in this article](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/01/seeding-customizing-aspnet-mvc.html).  You can also specify that the email be used for the identity with the [WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg569366%28v=vs.111%29.aspx).  I am not sure overriding RequiresUniqueEmail will give you the desired results. Look at this article on [decoupling SimpleMembership from MVC](http://kevin-junghans.blogspot.com/2013/03/decoupling-simplemembership-from-your.html). If you take this approach you can use the fluent API in EF to make sure that the email is unique.

Comment: Thanks read other articles on your site for SimpleMembership as well, very helpful

Answer (score 0):

The main registration is performed from this method:

```
WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.initializedatabaseconnection%28v=vs.111%29.aspx

**(edit)**
Not sure if you actually looked at the link, but this is where you wire up your connection name, table name, and columns. The reason why it works with no web.config entries is that Simple Membership is already enabled by default and you just need to call this method to activate it.

```
public static void InitializeDatabaseConnection(
string connectionStringName,
string userTableName,
string userIdColumn,
string userNameColumn,
bool autoCreateTables
)
```

If you want to build your own provider, you still need to register per the old way. This link may help:

http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2012/08/29/simplemembership-membership-providers-universal-providers-and-the-new-asp-net-4-5-web-forms-and-asp-net-mvc-4-templates.aspx

Comment: > where is the wiring for SimpleMembershipProvider in asp.net mvc4 and how to change it?  - That method is the wiring

Comment: It is called Simple because it provides basic functionality that is supposed to 'just work' with any database as long as you follow some basic naming conventions. It's goal is to not be as involved as writing a standard membership provider, but it sounds like that's the way you really want to go. Custom Simple Membership Provider is kind of an oxymoron.